# I don't know how to resize an image after starting the program

Tags: java, android

Don't judge too harshly, I'm working on a project that needs a gray border to stretch down in width and height to the bottom of the screen with 13dp padding,but nothing changed when I started the program. I thought about using **LayoutParams** and "fitXY", but something went wrong,

I thought about using **LayoutParams** and "fitXY", but something went wrong.
cml code of imageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollCorners"
        android:layout_width="341dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/scroll_view_rectangle" />
```

and java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int scaleheight(){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        return height;
    }
    public int scalewidth() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        return width;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int height = scaleheight();
        int width = scalewidth();
        //Переменная рамки
        ImageView ramka = (ImageView) (findViewById(R.id.ScrollCorners));
        //Изменение высоты и ширины
        int final_width, final_height;
        final_height= height - 268;
        final_width= width - 26;
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = ramka.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = final_width;
        layoutParams.height = final_height;
        ramka.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I apologize in advance for not knowing the basics of the engine, it's just that the project will have to be completed in a very limited time, there is no time for training.